# Can't "paste" in chat on iOS Safari

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-safari

On iOS, a "long press" in a text entry field will normally pull up a contextual test menu, with "paste," "select all," etc, depending on what's on the clipboard, and whether there's text in the box, selected, etc.

But in the main text box, that doesn't happen for me, which means it's not possible to paste a url or other long strings from my phone.

Interestingly, I *can* paste if I use the Chrome app from my phone, but in Safari, the "long press" menu doesn't appear in either mobile or "full" view.

I'm on the latest build of iOS (at the time I'm posting) - currently 8.2, and have the latest updates to both apps referenced.